# For which sets $E\subset \mathbb{Z}_n$ is $\widehat{1(E)}$ nonzero everywhere?

Tags: nt.number-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I apologise if this is well-known or straightforward.

Define the Fourier transform of the characteristic function of a subset $E\subseteq\mathbb{Z}_n$ by
$$
\widehat{1_E}(k)=\sum_{a \in E} \exp(-2 \pi i ak/n).
$$
If $n$ is an odd prime, this sum is always nonzero, for all nonempty proper subsets $E$. Can one characterize sets $E$ for which this sum is nonzero for $n$ composite?

Comment: Can you give the proof or reference for the result for odd primes? This isn't obvious to me. Certainly a proof must use both the primality of n, and that the function one is taking the Fourier transform of is the characteristic function of a set.

Comment: @MarkLewko Let me try. The cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_p(x)$ of degree $p$ is irreducible (by Eisenstein's criterion). Its roots are all the $p-$th roots of unity. $\sum_{a \in E} \omega_p^{ka}=0$ iff $\sum_{a \in E} \omega_p^{-ka}=0$. The first expression is zero iff a polynomial of degree strictly less than $p$ (one can reduce exponents mod $p$) divides $\Phi_p(x)$ which gives a contradiction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is true if and only if the vector space generated by the translates of $E$ has dimension $n$, which is a purely physical space characterization. This is the discrete Fourier version of Wiener's tauberian theorem, and follows from the fact that the Fourier transform takes convolutions to products.

Comment: But is there more direct characterization?

Comment: I would be interested in other characterisations as well.